# allow https to a single file on site with https redirecting to http (via web.config)

Tags: regex, web-config

My website was accessible by both HTTP and HTTPS until the SEO gents said we should go with one or the other (to avoid duplicate content). We've implemented an HTTPS -> HTTP redirect for all content on the site to do this which was set up via the web.config file.

However, now I need to open access of one file to HTTPS to load it properly in an HTTPS environment. Any assistance would be awesome.

Here is the redirect code:

```
<rule name="Redirect HTTPS to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^on$" ignoreCase="true"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

**Edit**: After thinking about it a bit more, what if I just wanted to allow images (.jpg, .gif, .png) to be accessed via HTTPS? I suppose what I'd need then is an inverse regex. like: match url="!((.jpg)(.gif)(.png))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by adding a rule that didn't redirect to HTTP for .jpg files:

```
<rule name="allow jpg to use https" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)(jpg)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^on$" ignoreCase="true"/>
    </conditions>
</rule>
```